# Theano import error/. collect2.exe: error:

Tags: python, c++, anaconda, theano, summarization

I have installed anaconda and used pip to install packages and theano.

## when i try to import theano, i get the following error.

TODO: 
    - Check max supported depth of recursion
    - CLazyLinker should add context information to errors caught during evaluation. Say what node we were on, add the traceback attached to the node.
- Clear containers of fully-useed intermediate results if allow_gc is 1
- Add timers for profiling
- Add support for profiling space used.

Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:

```
C:\Users\atiqu\Anaconda2\Library\mingw-w64\bin\g++.exe -shared -g -march=haswell -mmmx -mno-3dnow -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -mno-sse4a -mcx16 -msahf -mmovbe -maes -mno-sha -mpclmul -mpopcnt -mabm -mno-lwp -mfma -mno-fma4 -mno-xop -mbmi -mbmi2 -mno-tbm -mavx -mavx2 -msse4.2 -msse4.1 -mlzcnt -mno-rtm -mno-hle -mrdrnd -mf16c -mfsgsbase -mno-rdseed -mno-prfchw -mno-adx -mfxsr -mxsave -mxsaveopt -mno-avx512f -mno-avx512er -mno-avx512cd -mno-avx512pf -mno-prefetchwt1 -mno-clflushopt -mno-xsavec -mno-xsaves -mno-avx512dq -mno-avx512bw -mno-avx512vl -mno-avx512ifma -mno-avx512vbmi -mno-clwb -mno-pcommit -mno-mwaitx --param l1-cache-size=32 --param l1-cache-line-size=64 --param l2-cache-size=3072 -mtune=haswell -D NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -DMS_WIN64 -IC:\Users\atiqu\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\atiqu\Anaconda2\include -o C:\Users\atiqu\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.17763-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-2.7.16-64\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd C:\Users\atiqu\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.17763-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-2.7.16-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp -LC:\Users\atiqu\Anaconda2\libs -LC:\Users\atiqu\Anaconda2 -lpython27

===============================
C:\Users\atiqu\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBnrF5o.o: In function `unpack_list_of_ssize_t':
C:/Users/atiqu/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.17763-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-2.7.16-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:58: undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_TypeError'
C:/Users/atiqu/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.17763-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-2.7.16-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:68: undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_IndexError'
C:\Users\atiqu\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBnrF5o.o: In function `CLazyLinker_init':
C:/Users/atiqu/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.17763-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-2.7.16-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:341: undefined reference to `__imp_PyCObject_Type'
C:/Users/atiqu/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.17763-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-2.7.16-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:362: undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_IndexError'
C:/Users/atiqu/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.17763-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-2.7.16-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:380: undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_IndexError'
C:/Users/atiqu/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.17763-
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e2d3ee711e72> in <module>()
----> 1 import theano

C:\Users\atiqu\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.pyc in <module>()
     53     object2, utils
     54 
---> 55 from theano.compile import \
     56     SymbolicInput, In, \
     57     SymbolicOutput, Out, \

C:\Users\atiqu\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py in <module>()
      7         SpecifyShape, specify_shape, register_specify_shape_c_code)
      8 
----> 9 from theano.compile.function_module import *
     10 
     11 from theano.compile.mode import *

C:\Users\atiqu\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py in <module>()
     16 from theano import gof
     17 from theano.compat.python2x import partial
---> 18 import theano.compile.mode
     19 from theano.compile.io import (
     20     In, SymbolicInput, SymbolicInputKit, SymbolicOutput)

C:\Users\atiqu\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\mode.py in <module>()
      9 import  theano
     10 from theano import gof
---> 11 import theano.gof.vm
     12 from theano.configparser import config, AddConfigVar, StrParam
     13 from theano.compile.ops import register_view_op_c_code, _output_guard

C:\Users\atiqu\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py in <module>()
    566 
    567 try:
--> 568     import lazylinker_c
    569 
    570     class CVM(lazylinker_c.CLazyLinker, VM):

C:\Users\atiqu\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py in <module>()
    114             args = cmodule.GCC_compiler.compile_args()
    115             cmodule.GCC_compiler.compile_str(dirname, code, location=loc,
--> 116                                              preargs=args)
    117             # Save version into the __init__.py file.
    118             init_py = os.path.join(loc, '__init__.py')

C:\Users\atiqu\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.pyc in compile_str(module_name, src_code, location, include_dirs, lib_dirs, libs, preargs, py_module)
   2008             # difficult to read.
   2009             raise Exception('Compilation failed (return status=%s): %s' %
-> 2010                             (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
   2011         elif config.cmodule.compilation_warning and compile_stderr:
   2012             # Print errors just below the command line.

. collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status_Windows-10-10.0.17763-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-2.7.16-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:946: undefined reference to `__imp__Py_TrueStruct'Error'ndefined references to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct' followow
```